# Blocked connection from docker image to host (PHP and Xdebug in docker container with IntelliJ)

Tags: php, linux, docker, xdebug

Xcode running inside Docker Image is unable to connect to the client:

```
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)
```

The setup looks like this:

- `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```yaml
  version: '3'

  services:
    apache:
      container_name: apache
      extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
      build:
        context: ./local
        dockerfile: ./Apache.dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./httpdocs:/var/www/html/
        - ./local/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
  ```
- `Apache.Dockerfile`:

  ```
  FROM php:8.0-apache-bullseye

  RUN a2enmod rewrite

  RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli
  RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo
  RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql
  RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) exif

  RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
  ```
- `xdebug.ini`:

  ```
  zend_extension=xdebug.so
  xdebug.mode=develop,debug
  xdebug.start_with_request=yes
  xdebug.discover_client_host=0
  xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
  ```
- `docker version`

  ```
  Client: Docker Engine - Community
  Version:           20.10.16
  API version:       1.41
  Go version:        go1.17.10
  Git commit:        aa7e414
  Built:             Thu May 12 09:17:30 2022
  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
  Context:           default
  Experimental:      true

  Server: Docker Engine - Community
  Engine:
    Version:          20.10.16
    API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version:       go1.17.10
    Git commit:       f756502
    Built:            Thu May 12 09:15:33 2022
    OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
    Experimental:     false
  containerd:
    Version:          1.6.4
    GitCommit:        212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
  runc:
    Version:          1.1.1
    GitCommit:        v1.1.1-0-g52de29d
  docker-init:
    Version:          0.19.0
    GitCommit:        de40ad0
  ```
- Host: `Linux tuxmobile02 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 13:34:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- IntelliJ 2022.1, Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug

  - Xdebug port: 9003
  - [x] Can accept external connections
- UFW is disabled:

  ```
  $ ufw status
  Status inactive
  ```

Xdebug client (part of IntelliJ) is running and reachable from the **host**:

```
$ nmap -p 9003 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-27 10:32 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000049s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
9003/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

But it's not reachable from the **docker container**:

```
$ docker exec -it apache /bin/bash
root@cf85dafe5c66:/var/www/html# nmap -p 9003 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-05-27 08:33 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000041s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9003/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

The file `/etc/hosts` of the docker image looks as expected:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1  host.docker.internal
172.19.0.3  cf85dafe5c66
```

=> Any idea what may cause the blocked connection from the docker image to the host?

Comment: What are your interface IP address on the **host**? `host.docker.internal` ought to work here, unless you run a "root-less" docker container. If that's the case, you need to run `hostname -i` on the **host** and use that as IP address with `xdebug.client_host`.

Comment: And when you say *XCode Client*, do you mean *Xdebug Client as part of IntelliJ* ?

Comment: Hi @Derick : Yes, i mean *Xdebug Client as part of IntelliJ*.

Comment: IP Address on the host: `ifconfig docker0` => `172.17.0.1`. IP Address inside the docker image: `hostname -i` => `172.19.0.3`. Resolving of `host.docker.internal` works (see nmap: `Host is up (0.000041s latency)`), but the port `9003` is not reachable.

Comment: can you try to set `xdebug.client_host` to `172.19.0.3` (the output of `hostname -i`)?

Comment: This is returning the same result. As long as `nmap -p 9003 172.19.0.3` or `nmap -p 9003 host.docker.internal` returns `STATE closed`, changing from hostname to ip will not change anything. Looks like something is block traffic from the docker container to the host. I tested it with other services (using `nmap -p <port> host.docker.internal`) running on other ports on the host, they are all not reachable.

Comment: nmap is probably a poor thing to try. Can you use `netstat -a -n |grep LISTEN` on the host to see whether something is actually listening on port 9003?

Comment: `netstat -a -l | grep LISTEN | grep 9003` returns `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN` on the host. Surprisingly i was able to connect to port 9003 by using the address of my computer: `xdebug.client_host=192.168.178.46`

Comment: That's odd, D. Are you running rootless Docker?

Comment: Found this thread because docker rootless for me causes this exact issue and running it rootful works around it.
Still I don't understand yet, why rootless does not allow access to host ports.

Comment: @Derick thank you very much, hostname -i fixed my xdebug + rootless issue!