# PhpStorm inserts wrong client_host IP when trying to run debug session

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

PHP interpreter runs in docker container, Xdebug configuration is

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.idekey=Docker
xdebug.discover_client_host=on
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9011
xdebug.cli_color=1
```

When I run debugging session in tests, PhpStorm runs the execution string starting with

```
[docker-compose://[/home/Projects/service/docker-compose.yaml]:php/]:php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9011 -dxdebug.client_host=172.24.0.83 ...
```

Notice `-dxdebug.client_host=172.24.0.83` part... But `host.docker.internal` has another IP:

```text
$ docker-compose exec php ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
```

And of course it failed to start debug session. I didn't find any occurrence of this strange IP `172.24.0.83` anywhere in the project nor in the PhpStorm setting. How can I get rid of this obviously non-working condition in PhpStorm?

Comment: 1) If you insist on using `host.docker.internal` and stating that all other IPs will be wrong, ... then why do you have `xdebug.discover_client_host=on` line?

Comment: 2) Regardless of that, `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug` -- there is a `Settings` section at the very bottom (might be collapsed by default). There is an option called `Pass required configuration options through command line (still need to enable debug extension manually)` -- disable it. You will have to pass all needed extra params manually. **Alternatively** you can pass extra `-d` parameters in PHP Interpreter settings -- such params will be added after the IDE generated ones and therefore will overwrite them by your value.

Comment: 3) As to the "where it took that IP from". A few ideas that come into my head right now: A) Maybe it's cached from the past PHP Interpreter setup (try going into PHP Interpreters, find yours and check phpinfo() output -- the IDE should fetch a fresh one. B) May depend on your Docker / network setup (e.g. taking it from the wrong container or something). Cannot advise on this. C) May depend on how it runs the container -- makes a fresh one or reuses existing one.

Comment: Looks like I've got to the root of the problem. I cannot reach 9011 port on the host system from the docker container. Host's 9011 in listen mode according to netstat. Maybe some problem with rootlesskit of docker, maybe it's on host OS` network stack. Will investigate further, thanks

Comment: This looks to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402715/blocked-connection-from-docker-image-to-host-php-and-xdebug-in-docker-container — where the solution was to use the normal network address (f.e. 192.168.1.200) as value for `xdebug.client_host`, and not any of the internal bridge or docker networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. There is some steps to fix xdebug in cases like mine.

As @LazyOne mentioned, you can disable automatic passing of Xdebug CLI configuration option in `Settings/Preferences | PHP | Debug` in a `Settings` section by unchecking `Pass required configuration options through command line (still need to enable debug extension manually)` checkbox.

As @Derick mentioned, it is better to use your actual IP address of the machine (smth like 192.168.1.200) for `xdebug.client_host`. That is working for rootless docker also.