How to connect to Xdebug in WSL session from Windows host in PhpStorm?
On Windows 11, I use PhpStorm. The PHP script is executed through a Ubuntu instance via the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) within PhpStorm.
I use php8.3 and xdebug-3. Xdebug seems loaded as:
var_dump(extension_loaded('xdebug'));

prints true within my script.
Normal script execution works fine, but when I try to debug, I get the following error:
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

I assume that the issue is connecting to the WSL via the IP address and that PhpStorm is unable to connect via the 127.0.0.1 IP, but that it rather must use the WSL IP (in my case 172.27.48.1:9003). I don't know how to change how the command is generated.
This command PhpStorm generates looks like this:
[\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04]:/usr/bin/php --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 --exec /bin/bash -l -c "export TERM=xterm && export XDEBUG_CONFIG=idekey=17964 && export IDE_PHPUNIT_CUSTOM_LOADER=/mnt/c/Users/Philipp/Documents/GitHub/my-project/vendor/autoload.php && cd /mnt/c/Users/Philipp/Documents/GitHub/my-project && /usr/bin/php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 /mnt/c/Users/my-project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration /mnt/c/Users/my-project/tests --teamcity --cache-result-file=/mnt/c/Users/my-project/.phpunit.result.cache"

In the /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini to the to the proper WSL IP, yet, PhpStorm seems to ignore that value even though it says it reads the config from the WSL instance:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host=172.27.48.1

The generated command stays the same.
How do I connect to Xdebug on WSL via PhpStorm debug session?

Here's my Windows 11 PC ipconfig:
ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fritz.box
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1


Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::33b7:301b:55d3:45ff%32
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.240.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall)):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a5b:7f00:1e2d:30d6%62
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.27.48.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :



It's Xdebug that connect to the debug client (PhpStorm in your case) and NOT other way around. 2) So you need to use an IP of your Windows as seen from WSL.


@LazyOne How do I get that information? Is this the basic host IP of my Windows PC? (e.g. 192.168.178.100) or the one of the WSL Hyper-V firewall (that one uses 172.27.48.1) and was the one I configured.

@LazyOne I tried setting the Windows host's IP, and I get the same error. It appears the autogenerated command always tries to go through 127.0.0.1:9003.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76729511/phpstorm-inserts-wrong-client-host-ip-when-trying-to-run-debug-session

As the console output reads, you're connecting a firewall:

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))

And there is a documentation for that:
Configure Hyper-V firewall with PowerShell.

To obtain the WSL GUID:
Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator

To list the rules:
Get-NetFirewallHyperVRule -VMCreatorId '{WSL GUID}'

Allowing an inbound xdebug connection on :9003 might look about like this:
New-NetFirewallHyperVRule -VMCreatorId '{WSL GUID}' -Name xdebug -DisplayName "xdebug " -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPorts 9003

Or to allow all inbound traffic:
Set-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting -Name '{WSL GUID}' -DefaultInboundAction Allow 

Also see:

Get-NetFirewallHyperVVMCreator
New-NetFirewallHyperVRule
Set-NetFirewallHyperVVMSetting
GitHub


Should XDEBUG connect through the WSL Firewall IP, or should the windows host IP be used? This answer only relates to the Firewall IP allowance of traffic, yet how it pertains to connect to xdebug session from phpstorm is missing.

In PhpStorm, at
Settings > PHP > Debug > Settings

disable the flag:
Pass require configuration options through command line (still need to enable debug extension manually)

Now, these values are read from the php.ini / 20-xdebug.ini within your WSL instance.
Add this in your relevant php.ini or 20-xdebug.ini, e.g.: /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9003

The xdebug://gateway makes applying a dynamic and hence prone to change IP obsolete, it requires xdebug@3.2 though.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78923194/457268
